# Got a None return input after different inputs

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

Hello guys with the code below, after inputting a number and then a char, it returns None. I've got no clue about this one. Any help is welcome.
I've tried printing the values but it changes just on returning!

```
import string
def get_input_char(char):
    char = str.lower(input("Input a letter: "))
    if not char in string.ascii_letters or char == "" or char == None:
        print("Character " + char + " not valid. Try again.\n")
        char = str(get_input_char(char))
    else:
        return char
    print (char)

word_frag = ""
while True:
    word_frag += get_input_char("")
    print("\nThe current word fragment is " + word_frag)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark pointed out, the problem is that no value is returned if the first entered value is not valid.  There are also a few other things not quite right in your code:

- You're using recursion to test for valid values when a loop would be better.  This is mainly because of the large overheads involved in calling a function compared to a loop.  If you use a loop, you don't need to give the function an argument.
- It is better practice to check `char is None` instead of `char == None`.  Checking for equality may give unexpected results if the object you're testing has been customised to compare equal to `None`.  Checking identity (using `is`) is much more robust.
- However, it is not necessary to check for None at all, since *char* will always be a string.
- Your code implies that only one character is expected, but actually any string contained in *ascii_letters* would be accepted, e.g. "efgh".

I'd suggest rewriting the function something like this:

```
def get_input_char():
    while True:
        char = str.lower(input("Input a letter: "))
        if len(char) == 1 and char in string.ascii_letters:
            break
        else:
            print("Character '%s' not valid. Try again.\n" % char)
    return char
```

Comment: There's such a thing as being too helpful when the question looks like homework. I would hesitate to put code in such an answer, you're basically doing their homework for them.

Comment: Hmmm... didn't realize it was homework, its not tagged as such.  I'll try to be more careful in the future!

Comment: It wasn't labeled as homework, but when you look at the problem they're trying to solve it seems kind of obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot @aquavitae, Great help in my learning (I didn't know most of what you said)! Sorry for the lame question. It is homework. Not mine, though. Just took it for learning.

Comment: @MarkRansom, the help was much more than doing homework. There are some concepts that is hardly found and known for beginners. All I know of programming I learnd by myself (with books, videos, etc.). Not much yet though. You may give counsel instead of answer if you find it too like homework. It would help a lot. Thanks for your time, anyway!

Comment: @aquavitae, I am really thankful for your answer(I guess I understood it all), but I still can't understand why my function falls to the end. As I see it, it would return char or call the function again until it returns char. Would you help me? Thanks again!

Answer (score 7):

If your function falls through to the end, after the `print` statement, it doesn't return anything. The default value returned from a function is `None`.